# How to call an Oracle stored procedure using NHibernate programmatically?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures

(Apologise in advance if the question seems to be repeated. But as far as I looked at other questions on SF, they did not answer this question. And I am a NH beginner so thanks for tolerating my noob asking skills; Thanks)

How to call an Oracle stored procedure using NHibernate programmatically?

Assume we have a stored procedure in an Oracle db. How can I call it (even with native sql feature of NHibernate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ISession.CreateSQLQuery` method.

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC myStoredProc :p1, :p2");
query.SetParameter("p1", "someValue");
query.SetParameter("p2", 5);
```

Use either `List`, `UniqueResult`, or `ExecuteUpdate` to run the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can call sp which contains input and output variables:
https://github.com/lucianoybanez/csharp-useful-functions/blob/master/oracle-nhibernate-sp/OracleNhibernateStoreProcedure.cs

```
try
    {
        IDbCommand command = new OracleCommand();
        command.Connection = nHibernateSession.Connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.CommandText = "SP_NAME";

        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@i_userFirstName", "jhon"));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@i_userLastName", "Doe"));


        OracleParameter outputParameter =
            new OracleParameter("@o_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };
        command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

        nHibernateSession.Transaction.Enlist((DbCommand)command);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var result = ((OracleParameter)command.Parameters["@o_result"]).Value;

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex.GetType() == typeof(OracleException))
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }
```